# Lauch httpd built-in server

Tags: mojave

Trying to lauch `apachectl`
I get the error

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open
error log file /private/var/log/apache2/error_log. AH00015: Unable to
open logs
```

How can I safely solve? Without messing with the permissions I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that message I'm assuming you're attempting to run as your user. You need to start Apache with elevated privileges so that it can access the directory `/private/var/log/apache2` and file `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`.

Try running it like this instead:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

Or if it's already running:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

#### Running as root?

If you take a look at the results of the above `apachectl` script it should look something like this:

[image: ss]

The `httpd` process running as root is not the process that will be accepting connections, it'll start up more worker instances of `httpd` that'll do the actually servicing of TCP connections to access attempts on ports 80/443.

This will isolate any access so that it's through the worker instances which are running as the user `_www`, **NOT** `root`.

This type of interaction is typical with `*ctl` scripts which will require `root` privileges to access the filesystem for logs and require elevated privileges to bind a process to a port that's below 1024. This is a semi-magical number in TCP ports that denotes anything that's system's related whereas ports > 1024 any user can bind to.

#### What's _www?

This is what's traditionally called a service account or service user. This account's sole purpose is to own the processes that run as services, such as Apache webservers (`httpd`). Again this is for security/permission isolation on the off chance something bad happens, only the files and level of permissions granted to this user, `_www`, would be what's exposed to any break-ins.

You can use the `id` command in a terminal to see details about this service account.

```
$ id -a _www
uid=70(_www) gid=70(_www) groups=70(_www),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),100(_lpoperator)
```

#### References

- [Mac OS X Start / Stop / Restart Apache Web Server](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-macosx-starting-stopping-apache-web-server/)

Comment: are you sure launching apache as root is a good practice?

Comment: @alfredopacino - the actual apache/httpd process won't run as root, you're only being root to execute this service script.

Comment: related question about permission: what should I do to be able to freely operate with `/Library/WebServer/Documents`? I'm having permission issues there too (current owner `root:wheel`).

Comment: @alfredopacino that location should be accessible/owned by whatever user `httpd` is running as. In this example it's the user `_www`. If you use the `id -a _www` you can see the group names along with the UID + GID that are associated with this user account.

Comment: I'll open another question for that. Sadly it is a little difficult to find updated informations

Comment: @alfredopacino - sure thing, can you please mark this A'er as accepted so ppl know your original Q has been resolved?

Comment: @alfredopacino - also if you do a `ls -ld` for the directories under `/Library/WebServer/Documents` there should be some other sub-dirs under there I'd expect.

Comment: @alfredopacino - might be helpful - https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-web-server-in-mountain-lion/.

Comment: the fact I don't want to add a folder as user site, I want to use the document web root as I want without restrictions..

Comment: @alfredopacino - you'll need to then make that directory accessible to either the `_www` user directly or one of the groups that user's a member of based on the `id -a _www` output.

Comment: is there a best practice? After all I'm asking nothing that unusual..

Comment: @alfredopacino - I've never used Apache on macOS so am hesitant to tell a definitive A'er to where to put the Doc Root. I'm very familiar with Apache itself and the A'er is it depends what you want. I think you're following this guide? - https://www.mkyong.com/mac/mac-osx-where-is-default-localhost-folder/. This location makes sense to me, I would set the permissions here so that `_www` can access its `DocumentRoot` here.

Comment: This seems to be a common location for many, I'd perform the adjustments to the permissions as mentioned here - https://gist.github.com/jessedc/3488335 and here as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795183/how-to-take-control-of-apache2-webroot-on-os-x-mavericks. These are reasonable modifications IMO. I would be sure to isolate DocumentRoot is the goal.